# Partition shows in diskutil command output, but not the Disk Utility application

Tags: macos, partition, ssd

I deleted a partition using the `diskutil` command and now I can see the free space with `diskutil list`. However I cannot see the free space with the Disk Utility application.

How can I merge this free space (422.5 GB) with the current APFS partition?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you exit Disk Utility and reopen it?  Also, please don’t post photos of your output. Take a screenshot of your GUI app and copy\past text output to your question.  You can pipe the output directly to the clipboard.  Example:  `diskutil list | pbcopy` then paste (`Cmd-V`)

Comment: Ahh interesting, so I can copy paste in the recovery mode... Amazing indeed. Ah ok, I just checked. `pbcopy: command not found`

Comment: `% type pbcopy[return here] 
pbcopy is /usr/bin/pbcopy[return here]
%`

Comment: Normally while in recovery, I open Terminal window to enter commands, then close this window before opening the Disk Utility. If this is what Jamie (the OP) did, then exiting the Disk Utility and reopening (as Allan has suggested) would be pointless.

Comment: pbcopy is not a command is displayed on all those commands sadly.

Comment: An alternative to using `pbcopy` would be to highlight the text, then use Cmd-C to copy to the clipboard (which I think is easier anyway). Next, open Safari and edit your question. While editing, paste (Cmd-V) the text from the clipboard.

Comment: It wasn't clear when I made my inital comment you were in recovery.  That changes things a bit.  To save the output you could save it to a text file on a mounted USB drive `diskutil list | /Volumes/wherever` or `diskutil list | ssh foo@bar -T 'cat - >  diskutil_output.txt'`

Comment: An example of a question with basically the same answer would be: [Restore main APFS container to full disk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346993/restore-main-apfs-container-to-full-disk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge, there can be no partitions in between. In this case, there is the EFI partition (`disk0s3`) named `EFI - ASAHI`. The command below would remove this partition.

```
diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s3
```

You could then use the command below to add the free space back to the APFS partition (`disk0s2`).

```
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you very much indeed David!! This worked and was extremely easy

Comment: Good to know the answer worked. However because the answer worked, this question is probably a duplicate of many previous questions and probably should be closed as such.